# What does this mean? $length = null === $length ? strlen($data) : (int)$length ;

Tags: php

I'm aware of ternary operator, more or less. 
But I'm unable to read this line.

```
$length = null === $length ? strlen($data) : (int)$length ;
```

What does $length = null === $length means?

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Comment: that means "write only code" used by Real Programmers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means:

If the value of `$length` is `null`, assign `strlen($data)` to `$length`, otherwise `(int)$length`.

---

It is easier to understand if parenthesis are put at the right place:

```
$length = (null === $length) ? strlen($data) : (int)$length ;
```

Comment: +1 for the example with added parentheses, it really is much clearer.

Comment: Thank you, it really makes a difference those parentheses. :)

Answer (score 10):

It's the equivalent of

```
if (null === $length)
  $length = strlen($data);
else
  $length = (int)$length;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same as

```
if ($length === null)
{
    $length = strlen($data)
}
else
{
    $length = (int)$length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. :) Why to I start feeling like a dummy? :s 
;)

Answer (score 0):

It means

```
if (null === $length) {
   $length = strlen($data);
} else {
   $length = (int)$length ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$length = (null === $length ? strlen($data) : (int)$length ) ;


if (null === $length) {
  $length = strlen($data);
} else {
  $length = (int)$length;
}
```

The === means that $length must be exactly null.  See [PHP Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as $length = (null === $length ? strlen($data) : (int)$length );

Comment: Felix Kling parents? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a couple of parenthesis should make it clear:

```
$length = (null === $length ? strlen($data) : (int)$length);
```

Also the use of `null === $length` instead of `$length === null` is just coding style, mainly used to ne against stupid compilers that don't warn you about something like `if (foo = null) {` instead of `if (foo == null) {`.

Comment: Thanks. :) I didn't know about null===$length versus $length===null. :)

Answer (score 0):

a === b means a is identical to b and they are of the same type.

So if $length === null then $length = strlen($data) else $length